# Optimal Compound Indexes for $exists : true (sparse indexes)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

## Problem

I need to speedup this kind of query:

```
db.col.find({ a: "foobar", b: { $exists: true} });
```

## Data Distribution

### Existence of fields:

- The field `a` exists in **all** documents,
- The field `b` exists only in ~10% of them.

### Current Table Stats:

```
db.col.count() // 1,050,505
db.col.count({ a : "foobar" }) // 517.967
db.col.count({ a : "foobar", b : { $exists: true} }) // 44.922
db.col.count({ b : { $exists: true} }) // 88.981
```

### Futrue data growth:

So far two batches where loaded (2x around 500,000).
Each month another batch of ~500,000 documents will be added.
The `a` field is the name of this batch. Those newly added documents will have the same distribution of fields (around 10% of the newly loaded documents will have the `b` field)

## My tries and research

I created a sparse index on `{a:1, b:1}` but because `a` is present in all documents, that doesn't speed it up. Thats because the behaviour of sparse indexes in MongoDB. From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-compound-indexes):

> Sparse compound indexes that only contain ascending/descending index keys will index a document as long as the document contains at least one of the keys.

This is the `.explain()` of the upper query:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "myCol",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "a" : {
                        "$eq" : "foobar"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "b" : {
                        "$exists" : true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "b" : {
                        "$exists" : true
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "a" : 1,
                        "b" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "a_1_b_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "a" : [ 
                            "[\"foobar\", \"foobar\"]"
                        ],
                        "b" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 44922,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 208656,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 517967,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 517967,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "nReturned" : 44922,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 180672,
            "works" : 550772,
            "advanced" : 44922,
            "needTime" : 473045,
            "needFetch" : 32804,
            "saveState" : 41051,
            "restoreState" : 41051,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "b" : {
                        "$exists" : true
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 44922,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 180612,
                "works" : 550772,
                "advanced" : 44922,
                "needTime" : 473045,
                "needFetch" : 32804,
                "saveState" : 41051,
                "restoreState" : 41051,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 517967,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 517967,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3035,
                    "works" : 517967,
                    "advanced" : 517967,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 41051,
                    "restoreState" : 41051,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "a" : 1,
                        "b" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "a_1_b_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "a" : [ 
                            "[\"foobar\", \"foobar\"]"
                        ],
                        "b" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 517967, // INFO: I think that this is too much. These are all documents having a:"foobar"
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : []
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "productive-mongodb-16",
        "port" : 27000,
        "version" : "3.0.1",
        "gitVersion" : "534b5a3f9d10f00cd27737fbcd951032248b5952"
    }
}
```

`a` exists in all 1,000,000 documents and 520,000 of them have `a:"foobar"`. In the whole collection 88,000 having the `b` field.

How to speedup my query (so that IXSCAN returns only 44k instead of 520k)?

Comment: You said `a` exists in most documents, but in how many documents have `a: 'foobar'` on average? More or less than those where `b : { $exists: true}`?

Comment: How are `.{ "a": "foobar" }` and `{ "a": "foobar", "b": { "$exits": true } }` equal in any way? The cleary are not, but there is more. As the [documentation states](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-index-and-incomplete-results) *"If a sparse index would result in an incomplete result set for queries and sort operations, MongoDB will not use that index"*. Therefore a "sparse" index that is "compound" expects "both" elements to be present. Asking for a test on "am I present" clearly does not use the index. Ask for the value of "b" or just define another index on "a" only.

Comment: @Philipp I added the answer to my question (see current table stats).

Comment: @BlakesSeven We query with `$exists : true` which enforces a complete resultset. Thats why mongodb tries to use the index. So I don't know whether your assumption is still valid?

Comment: @d0x Not true. I gave an answer that should explain this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you do not seem to be understanding here is that [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) cannot "grab" an index in any way, even where sparse.
 As the documentation itself says:

> *"If a sparse index would result in an incomplete result set for queries and sort operations, MongoDB will not use that index"*

The example given in those pages is an `{ "$exists": false }` query. But the reverse logical condition does not make any difference here.

In order to get the "full benefit" of a "sparse" index then you need to consider the "type" of data it holds and query appropriately.

For numeric, something like:

```js
db.collection.find({ "a": "foobar", "b": { "$gte": -9999, "$lte": 9999 } })
```

Which uses an index, and the sparse one. Or for text based:

```js
db.collection.find({ "a": "foobar", "b": /.+/ })
```

Which will also use the sparse index and only look at those where "b" was defined.

For "arrays" then "be careful". As the value being looked at is probably one of the above unless you did this:

```js
db.collection.insert({ "a": 1, "b": [[]] })
```

Where then this is okay:

```js
db.ab.find({ "a": 1, "b": { "$type": 4 } })
```

But is not really going to use the "sparse" index either for the same reasons `$exists` won`t work here.

So you need to understand what the terms mean here are, and "query appropriately" in order to use the index definitions that you create if you expect the maximum performance.

These are clear examples you can test for yourself and see the results are true. I do wish the core documentation was clearer on these points, but I am also aware many have tried to contribute ( and have produced excellent explainations ) but none of these have been included to date.

Guess that is why you are asking here.

Comment: @d0x I could see you were not "getting it" on the comment I gave so I thought a "long form" was required. Glad you can see it now, which is all I did it for.

Comment: How would you cope with the case where the field you're querying on is an array?