# MongoDB: Yet another trouble with compound, sparse and unique indexes

Tags: mongodb

I have documents with a `slugID` and `parentID` properties:

```
{
    slugID: <string>,  // optional
    parentID: <ObjectID>,
    ...
}
```

Basicaly, the `slugID` is something that can be used in an URL, while `parentID` is the parent resource (the parent resource in the URL).

However, not all resources has a `slugID`, in that case this property **does not exist in the document.**

By the way, I want to enforce uniqueness of slugs among children of the same parent (so an URL can be resolved to find a unique resource/document).

Naturally, I came up with a compound index `{ slugID: 1, parentID: 1}` with the options `{ sparse: true, unique: true }`.

But surprisingly, *sparse index* does not behave like it should on compound indexes: if *ANY* property of the index exists, it will be indexed (was expecting: if *ANY* property is missing, it is NOT indexed).

In my case, `parentID` is always defined, but `slugID` is not mandatory, so as a result I get the duplicate key error every time two documents don't have `slugID` for the same parent...

So... what is the workaround? (**EDIT:** in this question, I'm concerned with the *uniqueness* of the (slugID,parentID) tuple *if slugID exists*).

I have only application-side solution, and none of them really satisfy me.

PS: I know there are other similar questions (compound, sparse and unique indexes), but the workaround does not fit my use case very well.

PS2: the offending queries:

```
> db.so.ensureIndex( { parentID: 1 , slugID: 1 } , { sparse: true , unique: true } )
> db.so.insert( { parentID: "id1" } )
> db.so.insert( { parentID: "id1" } )
> E11000 duplicate key error index: test.so.$parentID_1_slugID_1  dup key: { : "id1", : null }
```

Comment: Well you don't give any detail here about how you are querying. But I did give this recent answer about compound indexes with he "sparse" property that likely is relevant to what you are asking. So take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340290/optimal-compound-indexes-for-exists-true-sparse-indexes/31342367#31342367

Comment: Here it is the uniqueness of the (slugID,parentID) *if the slugID exists* that bother me. I will edit my question ;)

Comment: You probably should . `{ "slug": 1 }` and `{ "slug": 1, "parentId": null }` are essentially the same thing thus producing a duplicate when "unique". Also still not seeing a case that produces the error in your question.